# why I m getting TypeError: Failed to fetch?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, cors

I got a fetched error type when trying to send data from a react app .

note that I m using cores.
and it s working fine on localhost with client side and not when hosting it online.

Note : I get result from json when using postman like this :

```
{
"success":"true",
"ID":"token"
}
```

this is the back-end code source in expressjs :

```
router.post("/sickers/user/login/", cors(), (req, res) => {

    var values = req.body;
    var pass = values.password;
    var email = values.email;
    if (pass !== null || pass !== "") {
        try {

            con.query("SELECT Password ,ID FROM `sickers` WHERE Email='" + email + "'", function(err, rows, field) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send("an error detected try later");
                } else {
                    try {
                        if (pass == rows[0].Password) {
                            //create the signed function
                            jwt.sign(rows[0].ID, "secretkey", (err, token) => {
                                    res.json({ success: "true", ID: token })
                                })
                                //session.session( )
                        } else {
                            res.json({ success: "false" });
                        }
                    } catch {
                        res.json({ success: "false" });
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            res.json({ success: "false" });
        }
    }
});
```

and client method is :

```
//submit values
const submithandler=async (e)=> {
   e.preventDefault();
     try{
         console.log('start')
            await fetch('url/api/sickers/user/login/',{
                      method:'post',
                      headers:{
                             'Accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                               },
                         body:JSON.stringify({
                                     password:password,
                                     email:email
                                            })
                               })
                                  .then(response => 
                                    {
                                console.log("response");
                            response.json().then(data => 
                                {
                                    console.log(data);
                               if(data.success=="true")
                                {
                            sessionStorage.setItem('ID',data.ID);
                            window.location.reload();
                            seterr("");
                                 }
                        else
                                 {
                                  seterr("try again");
                                 }
                             });
                          });
                 }
                 catch(e)
                 {
                   console.log(e)
                 }
}
```

do I miss something here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your CORS configuration on the server? On localhost both applications are communicating over the same DNS (localhost) but if hosted on a cloud network of some type, they could be on different domains causing the CORS issue if not configured properly

Comment: thanks for reply , I will try to add the permission , I think it's exactly the problem , cause I did not find .htaccess file on my root or it's hidden.

Comment: I have added two lines in .htaccess file for allow headers but I notice that I still have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this before by adding cores to .htaccess on server , or hosting the full project with it's back and front ends into the same server.